# Spring Bootでデータベースから値を取ってきて表示する時にNullpointerExceptionが出ます。

Tags: java, gradle, spring, nullpointerexception

Spring Bootでデータベースから値を取ってくる時にぬるぽが出ます。ソースは以下です。

●application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/attendance_management 
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password=パスワード 
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

●EmployeeMaster.java

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity // このクラスはEntityとして登録しますよ、とspringに教えてます 
public class EmployeeMaster { 

    @Id // プライマリーキーのものに設定してください 
    @GeneratedValue // 主に数字に対して、順番に一意に設定しますよ、の意味 
    protected String empID;

    @Column // ただの変数じゃなくて、DBのカラムだよ、の意味 
    protected String pwd;

    // setter & getter --------------------- 
    public String getEmpID() { 
        return empID;
    } 

    public void setEmpID(String employee_id) { 
        this.empID = employee_id;
    } 

    public void setPassword(String password) { 
        this.pwd = password;
    } 

    public String getPassword(){ 
        return pwd;
    } 

    // constructor -------------------------- 
    public EmployeeMaster(){ 
        super();
    } 

    public EmployeeMaster(String id, String pass){ 
        super();
        this.empID =id;
        this.pwd = pass;
    } 

}
```

●EmployeeMasterRepository.java

```
package repository; 

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service; 

import entity.EmployeeMaster; 

@Service 
@Repository 
public interface EmployeeMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<EmployeeMaster, String>{ 
}
```

●ViewController.java

```
package common; 

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired; 
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component; 
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody; 

import repository.EmployeeMasterRepository; 
import entity.EmployeeMaster; 

@Component 
@Controller 
@EnableAutoConfiguration 
public class ViewController { 

    @Autowired(required=false) 
    // リポジトリを紐づけます 
    EmployeeMasterRepository repository; 

    @RequestMapping("/") 
    @ResponseBody 
    public String home() { 

        // 全件取得します 
        Iterable<EmployeeMaster> list = repository.findAll(); 

        // 取得した内容を出力します 
        for (EmployeeMaster emp : list) { 
            System.out.println(emp.getEmpID() + ":" + emp.getPassword()); 
        } 
        return "Hello!"; 
    } 

}
```

<エラーコード>

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null 
    at common.ViewController.home(ViewController.java:29) 
    at common.ViewController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$2e3276a4.invoke(<generated>) 
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) 
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) 
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281) 
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) 
    at common.ViewController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3d3ad38.home(<generated>) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) 
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) 
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) 
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) 
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537) 
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085) 
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658) 
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

なおweb.xmlなどの設定ファイルはありません。 
いくらググっても有効な解決策を見つけられなかったので質問させて頂きました。 
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

---

[image: 階層構造]

回答ありがとうございます。すみません、まだプログラミング初心者なもんで・・。
階層構造は上記のようになっています。ご検討お願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

スタックトレースでViewControllerの29行目とあって微妙にViewController.javaの行数がずれているのですが、おそらく `repository.findAll()` の部分での `NullPointerException` だと思います。

`@ComponentScan` をつけると、Spring Frameworkがそのクラスと同じパッケージ配下のクラスを自動的にスキャンしてビーン登録などをしてくれます。
最新のSpring Bootであれば、`@ComponentScan` を含んだ `@SpringBootApplication` をmainメソッドのあるクラスにつけるのが普通ですが、そのクラスのパッケージとコントローラやリポジトリのコントローラが違っているので、自動コンポーネントスキャン対象になっていないとか、DI対象になっていない、などが発生しているのではないでしょうか。

その辺を見直すとよいと思います。

簡単には、`@SpringBootApplication` をつけるメインクラスをアプリのベース名のパッケージにして(たとえば `hoge`)、他のパッケージは `hoge.common`, `hoge.repository` などとしておけば取りこぼしがなくなるはずです。

---

今追加されたのを見ると `Application` クラスが `common` パッケージなので、`repository` パッケージが自動スキャンされていない→NPE発生、の流れだとおもいます。

Comment: 追加されたと思ったら追加情報消えてますね。回答として追加してしまったので一度消したのかな？

Comment: あら、再び追加情報(質問者からの回答)が見えるようになってました。誰かの承認待ちだったのか、クラスタ内での情報の伝播に時間がかかっだけなのか...

Comment: すいません、一回削除してまた追加したんです笑
それより回答ありがとうございました！その通りにやれば
うまく行きました。パッケージ名って重要なんですね..

Answer (score 1):

ComponentScanの設定が間違っているのでは？他のクラスとパッケージ構成みないとわからないですね。

しかしまぁ、アノテーションの付け方がめちゃくちゃ。。

本題と関係ありませんが、

- `ViewController`には`@Controller`だけでOKです。`@Controller`は`@Component`の意味も兼ねているので、`@Component`が重複しています。`@EnableAutoConfiguration`はhaコントローラーにつけるものではなく、アプリケーションのエントリポイントにつけてください(`main`メソッドがあるクラス)
- `EmployeeMasterRepository`に`@Service`も`@Repository`も不要です。`JpaRepository`を`implements`していれば認識されます。(ちなみに`JpaRepository`ではない場合も通常は`@Service`と`@Repository`は同時につけません。)

Comment: 丁寧にありがとうございます！解決しました！
アノテーションもうちょっと勉強します。